# Opening a new window on a button click in java

Tags: java, button, dialog

I'm just starting with using interfaces in java, I'm okay with having just one window and that doing what i need. But i now want to link two windows together e.g.

Frame 1 opens.
user chooses button1 (enter data).
Frame 2 opens so user can enter the data.

Code for Frame 1:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Task_3 extends JFrame {
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    public Task_3(){

      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      btn1 = new Button("Enter data");
      add(btn1);
      btn2 = new Button("Check who is going");
      add(btn2);
      btn3 = new Button("View costs");
      add(btn3);

      setTitle("Event Costs");
      setSize(280, 150);
      setVisible(true);

      // close the window
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
      {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
         dispose();
         System.exit(0); //calling the method is a must
      }
      });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Task_3();
    }
}
```

Code for Frame 2:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Task1GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    private Label lblInput;
    private Label lblOutput;
    private TextField tfInput;
    private TextField tfOutput;
    private int sum = 0;

    public Task1GUI(){
        setLayout( new FlowLayout());

        lblInput = new Label("Enter number of students: ");
        add(lblInput);

        tfInput = new TextField(5);
        add(tfInput);

        tfInput.addActionListener(this);

        lblOutput = new Label("The cost per student is: ");
        add(lblOutput);

        tfOutput = new TextField(20);
        tfOutput.setEditable(false);
        add(tfOutput);

        setTitle("Task1GUI");
        setSize(350, 120);
        setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
      {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
         dispose();
         System.exit(0); //calling the method is a must
      }
      });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Task1GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        int numOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
        int coachCost = 550;
        int entrycost = 30;
        int totalcost;
        int numFree;
        int Discount;
        int costPerPerson;
        if(numOfStudents<45){
        totalcost = coachCost+(numOfStudents*30);
        numFree = numOfStudents/10;
        Discount = numFree*30;
        costPerPerson = (totalcost-Discount)/numOfStudents;
        tfInput.setText("");
        tfOutput.setText(costPerPerson+"");
    }
    else{
        tfOutput.setText("Too mant students entered");
    }
    }
}
```

Basically I would like some help with linking these two programs together so that the user can open the first frame choose which action they would like to do.

I have only been working with the console up until very recently so if my code is not perfect I apologise but I would really appreciate any help with this.

I would eventually like to get this program https://repl.it/repls/FondAptXeme to have a GUI if this helps at all.

Thanks

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: I would like to have the user select a button from the first window which then in turn opens a second window where they can for example enter data.

Comment: And what problem do you have implementing this? I do understand what you want, it's where you're stuck I don't get.

Comment: I dont know how to implement it. I'm okay with creating individual windows but not linking them together if that makes sense.

Comment: and why do you think there is a difference between the two?

Comment: Well I'm unsure of how to to implement it so when the button is clicked the second window will open.

Comment: exactly the same as you do in your main method, you just put the code in your actionPerformed method of the Listener

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand

Comment: you need to do exactly what you are already doing. The only difference is, instead of putting it in the main method of the same class, you put it in the actionPerformed of an actionListener in the other class.

Comment: I know people are suggesting a second `JFrame`, this may not meet your needs if you then need to get the data which is entered by the user for other purposes.  Instead, have a look at [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) - they allow you to prompt the user for information in such away that the code will stop at the point the window is made visible and continue when it's closed, so you can extract the information you need from it - should you wish to

Comment: MadProgrammer is that a problem when using two JFrames? He could simply pass his "main" JFrame to the second JFrame's constructor and call an importData function there once the window-closing callback is executed.

Comment: Okay this might help i've copied the program i would like to convert into having a GUI on repl.

https://repl.it/repls/FondAptXeme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new JFrame and setting the visibility of your new JFrame to "true" in the button's action listener. Something like this:

```
private JFrame secondFrame = new JFrame("My 2nd Window!");
```

and then in your button1 action listener you do:

```
secondFrame.setVisible(true);
```

EDIT:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Task_3 extends JFrame {
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    private Task1GUI task1Gui = new Task1GUI();

    public Task_3(){

      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      btn1 = new Button("Enter data");
      btn1.addActionListener(this); //this refers to your current frame
      add(btn1);
      btn2 = new Button("Check who is going");
      add(btn2);
      btn3 = new Button("View costs");
      add(btn3);

      setTitle("Event Costs");
      setSize(280, 150);
      setVisible(true);

      // close the window
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
      {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
         dispose();
         System.exit(0); //calling the method is a must
      }
      });

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Task_3();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        task1Gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this reply.

sorry but im unsure as to what you mean by this could you possibly explain in more detail please?

thanks

Comment: Hi, yes no problem. So basically if you want a new window you either use a JFrame or a JDialog depending on the purpose. To control the visibility of these frames you set the visibility attribute to either true or false. If you have doubts about how to add the actionListener to your button please see the below example from the java documentation: 

[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Okay, so i now understand that i need to use frames not windows(dialog's) but what I am struggling with is setting these up as two separate frames and then calling one after a button has been clicked. I understand that I will need to have an actionlistener on the button but again I'm not sure how to implement this. I've tried a few things but each time it just puts everything onto the first frame.

Comment: @AlexanderJamesStephens, please see my updated answer to make it a bit more clear as to what I'm trying to show. This should work fine, if it does not, perhaps you should let your Task1GUI class extend JFrame instead of Frame.

Comment: I'm glad friend! If you don't mind, please mark the answer as the correct one if it helped you so others may benefit from it as well in the future. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two programs there (2x main), though the second one (Task1Gui) should in fact just be an object inside your first class.

Declare Task1Gui in Task3 and add an `actionListener` to one of the buttons (in that case btn1):

```
private Task1Gui enterDataFrame;

btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        enterDataFrame= new Task1Gui();
    }
});
```

Make sure you change your Task1Gui's main method and change the windowListener so only your window gets closed and disposed, not your whole program:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
   {
      dispose();
   }
});
```

Also, I would change the actionListener of your tfInput textfield to an annonymous inner type:

```
tfInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int numOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
                    int coachCost = 550;
                    int entrycost = 30;
                    int totalcost;
                    int numFree;
                    int Discount;
                    int costPerPerson;

                    if(numOfStudents < 45){
                        totalcost = coachCost + (numOfStudents * 30);
                        numFree = numOfStudents / 10;
                        Discount = numFree * 30;
                        costPerPerson = (totalcost-Discount)/numOfStudents;
                        tfInput.setText("");
                        tfOutput.setText(costPerPerson + "");
                    }

                    else {
                        tfOutput.setText("Too mant students entered");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Oh and is there a reason for you using "JFrame" (swing) on one class and "Frame" (awt) on the other?

Comment: I've  changed my post is this correct?

The only reason is that i've been following various tutorials to try and understand. It could be very bad technique I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, try it if you want

JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("Sipariş Ver");

```
    btnNewButton_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Final().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```